# Запятая перед тире (2)

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире

Нужна ли запятая перед тире в таком предложении:

"**Возможно, Мураками до сих пор участвует в соревнованиях – по крайней мере, мы нашли упоминание об этом, сделанное, когда ему было 65**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Запятая ставится в качестве дополнительного знака препинания:

**Возможно, Мураками до сих пор участвует в соревнованиях, – по крайней мере, мы нашли упоминание об этом, сделанное, когда ему было 65.**

[Розенталь. § 25. Вводные слова и словосочетания](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122)

Дополнительный знак препинания может подчеркивать **причинно-следственные или присоединительные отношения между частями предложения**: Проверить его слова было трудно, — **очевидно**, обстоятельства сильно изменились; Появились какие-то новые мысли, — **может быт**ь, они никогда уже не повторятся; Бабушка уже топчется около стола, — **должно быть**, хочет зажечь огонь (Гл.).

Comment: Здесь не запятая ставится в качестве дополнительного знака препинания, а тире.